# Manual lock in Snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can we manually lock a table in Snowflake?
I have multiple processes running together which will select data from a table.

If table is not locked all processes running together will fetch same record.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If the table is not locked then the select queries will fetch the most up-to-date records.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to lock a table explicitly in Snowflake. You may check the *transactions* page for more information:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#resource-locking

It seems you have some processes running in parallel, but you want them to run in sequence. If this is the case, you better change your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Some statements (like the `delete`) [lock](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions#resource-locking) the table and they only release the lock when the transaction is either comitted or rolled back.
Example

```sql
-- create a dummy table
create table my_schema.my_table(id integer);

-- execute this in two different sessions
begin;
delete from my_schema.my_table where UUID_STRING() = 'acquire lock'; --predicate is always false, no row will be deleted.
CALL SYSTEM$WAIT(30); -- do stuff with my_schema.my_table
commit;

-- execute this in another sessions (a third one)
show locks;
```

The `show locks` will show that the first transaction to run holds the lock on the table and the second is waiting for it. It stops at the `delete` statement.

I think with the above you force the two transactions to run in sequence.